# How increment the code coverage percent in Sonar Qube result for AEM Cloud?

Tags: sonarqube, aem

I am using Adobe Cloud CI/CD build pipeline for my build process which is integrated with Sonar Qube.

As a code Model, I have a very simple POJO, with 3 attributes, `@Inject` annotation for each one, and getters and setters as usual.

When I push the code to `remote/develop` the SonarQube starts to test the code, then I can see the code coverage is under 50% all the time as shown in the below image.

[image]

The question is, how can I increment that code coverage above 50% in order to pass the test?

Comment: Code coverage usually refers to how much of your code is tested in the unit test classes. Do you have a JUnit for these POJOs?

Comment: Not yet, do you have any example? That's maybe the reason, I nee some JUnit Testing for them

Comment: Take a look at the Adobe Core Components (hosted on GitHub) inside the test folders.

Comment: FYI I was able to increment the code coverage once I added the Unit Test classes. Look at [this document](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/getting-started-wknd-tutorial-develop/unit-testing.html) as a reference.

Comment: Excellent, that was exactly what I had on my mind.